# IDE for Pro*C/C++ Developement and Debugging in Linux

Tags: oracle

I would like to know which IDE best support IDE for Pro*C/C++ Developement and Debugging in Linux.

I tried using Eclipse CDT but it only helped in easy code navigation and searching.

Please help me in the regard.

SK

Comment: vim. Works great for me.

Comment: Does vim do syntax checking?

Comment: Vim itself doesn't know anything about C++, but there are a number of useful plugins, e.g. Valloric YCM that I use myself that will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try codeblocks or codelite,but does the tool match your words"best,Pro" ...I don't know